# Parsing indented text with duplicate keys

Tags: perl, parsing

I have a multi-line indented text string that looks-like YAML, with the exception of duplicate keys. I would like to parse the string into a Perl hash, and turn values of duplicate keys into arrays.

I couldn't figure out how to use any of the existing parsers [`Marpa::R2`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Marpa::R2), [`Parser::MGC`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parser::MGC), [`Parse::RecDescent`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parse::RecDescent) and I resorted to an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29311868/2035207) by [@James Shaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1649952/james-shaw).

I now have an array of nodes, which links to the parent; however, I'm stuck at turning it into a Perl structure.

***Sample input file***

```yaml
info:
    family: skywalker

    person:
        id: 0
        status: active

        details:
            gender: male

            name:
                first: Anakin
                last: Skywalker

        children: Leia1
        children: Han Solo1

    person:
        id: 58
        status: active

        details:
            gender: female

            name:
                first: Padme
                last: Amidala

        children: Leia2
        children: Han Solo2
```

***Desired Perl structure***

```perl
{
    'info' => {
        'family' => 'skywalker',
        'person' => [
            {
                'id'      => 0,
                'status'  => 'active',
                'details' => {
                    'gender' => 'male',
                    'name'   => {
                        'first' => 'Anakin',
                        'last'  => 'Skywalker'
                    }
                },
                'children' => [ 'Leia1', 'Han Solo1' ],
            },
            {
                'id'      => 58,
                'status'  => 'active',
                'details' => {
                    'gender' => 'female',
                    'name'   => {
                        'first' => 'Padme',
                        'last'  => 'Amidala'
                    }
                },
                'children' => [ 'Leia2', 'Han Solo2' ],
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

***Current code***

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use v5.36;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

# Node hierarchy
package Node;

sub new ( $class, $depth, $name, $value ) {
    my $self = {
        Name   => $name,
        Value  => $value,
        Depth  => $depth,
        Parent => undef,
    };
    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
}

# Main program
package main;

sub parse ($data) {
    my @lines = split /\n/, $data;
    my $queue;
    my $root;
    my $current;
    my $previous;

    foreach my $line (@lines) {
        if ( my ( $spaces, $key, $val ) = $line =~ /^(\s*)(\S+):(?:\s(.+))?$/ )
        {
            my $depth = length($spaces) / 4;
            if ( !$root ) {
                $root    = Node->new( $depth, $key, $val );
                $current = $root;
            }
            else {
                $previous = $current;
                $current  = Node->new( $depth, $key, $val );

                if ( $current->{Depth} > $previous->{Depth} ) {
                    $current->{Parent} = $previous;
                }
                elsif ( $current->{Depth} == $previous->{Depth} ) {
                    $current->{Parent} = $previous->{Parent};
                }
                else {
                    my ($previousSibling) =
                      grep { $_->{Depth} == $current->{Depth} } @$queue;
                    $current->{Parent} =
                      $previousSibling ? $previousSibling->{Parent} : undef;
                }
            }
            push @$queue, $current;
        }
    }

    return $queue;
}

# Main
my $data  = do { local $/; <> };
my $nodes = parse($data);

### Turn into hash?
foreach my $node (@$nodes) {
    my $parents = [];
    my $p = $node;
    while ( $p->{Parent} ) {
        unshift @$parents, $p->{Parent}->{Name};
        $p = $p->{Parent};
    }
    # Key: @$parents . $node->{Name}
    # Value: $node->{Value}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing with `YAML::PP` croaks here:
https://github.com/perlpunk/YAML-PP-p5/blob/327e74b2816c8599295b70513822036bd3dd5d1e/lib/YAML/PP/Constructor.pm#L213

I can't quite figure out if it's possible to get a custom `on_data` callback in there.

Changing the code manually from:

```perl
213             if ($seen{ $key }++ and not $self->duplicate_keys) {                                                     
214                 croak "Duplicate key '$key'";
215             }
216             $$hash->{ $key } = $value;
```

To:

```perl
213             if ($seen{ $key }++ and not $self->duplicate_keys) {
214                 if (ref $$hash->{ $key } eq 'ARRAY') {                                                            
215                     push @{$$hash->{ $key }}, $value;
216                 } else {
217                     $$hash->{ $key } = [ $$hash->{ $key }, $value ];
218                 } 
219             } else {
220                 $$hash->{ $key } = $value;
221             }
```

Produces:

```perl
$VAR1 = {
  'info' => {
    'family' => 'skywalker',
    'person' => [
      {
        'id' => 0,
        'status' => 'active',
        'details' => {
          'gender' => 'male',
          'name' => {
            'first' => 'Anakin',
            'last' => 'Skywalker'
          }
        },
        'children' => [
          'Leia1',
          'Han Solo1'
        ]
      },
      {
        'id' => 58,
        'status' => 'active',
        'details' => {
          'gender' => 'female',
          'name' => {
            'first' => 'Padme',
            'last' => 'Amidala'
          }
        },
        'children' => [
          'Leia2',
          'Han Solo2'
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Code used:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Indent = 1;

use YAML::PP;
use YAML::PP::Common qw/ :PRESERVE /;

my $yp = YAML::PP->new(
    preserve => PRESERVE_ORDER,
);

my $yaml = <<'EOM';
info:
    family: skywalker

    person:
        id: 0
        status: active

        details:
            gender: male

            name:
                first: Anakin
                last: Skywalker

        children: Leia1
        children: Han Solo1

    person:
        id: 58
        status: active

        details:
            gender: female

            name:
                first: Padme
                last: Amidala

        children: Leia2
        children: Han Solo2
EOM

my $data = $yp->load_string($yaml);
warn Dumper $data;

#$yaml = $yp->dump_string($data);
#warn Dumper $yaml
```

Comment: Thank you but I couldn't get it to work - I get the last entry, and no array (e.g. `'children' => 'Han Solo2'`). Should I use any special `options`? I replaced [Line 214 YAML::PP@0.036](https://github.com/perlpunk/YAML-PP-p5/blob/327e74b2816c8599295b70513822036bd3dd5d1e/lib/YAML/PP/Constructor.pm#L214), with your lines 214-to-218.

Comment: Perhaps my example was a bit unclear, I replaced lines 213-216 with the snippet shown, not just 214.